# javascript - regex for replace citation tag in sentence (scientific paper)

Tags: javascript, regex

Give a sentence:

```
We used mallet toolkit (Mccallum, 2002) for CRF implementation and word2vec (Mikolov et. al, 2013) for word embedding.
```

I want to replace all valid citation tag with *(citation)*

```
We used mallet toolkit (citation) for CRF implementation and word2vec (citation) for word embedding.
```

how to create regex to make sure valid pattern `(` + `text` + `,` + `year`+ `)` on javascript?

i use:

```
sentence.replace(/\(.*\,\d{4}\)/,'(citation)');
target.replace(/\(.*\,\d{4}\)/,'(citation)');
```

work on https://regex101.com/, but did not when running using nodejs

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please edit your question to include an attempt for us to help debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close - you just need the ? lazy quantifier added:

```
\(.*?,\s+\d{4}\)
```

and I added the `\s+` for clarity that there is a space there (hard to see in your code).

In regex101.com select the save regex and it will give you a link with your inputs populating the relevant fields, such as [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/zzCfkR/1).